# Powershell list files by particular owner

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

Beginner here.
How can I modify this script to list files owned by a particular user rather than listing every single file.  For instance, I only want to see files owned by user john doe.

```
Set-StrictMode -Version Latest $files = Get-ChildItem foreach($file in $files) {$owner=(Get-Acl $file).Owner $file | Add-Member NoteProperty Owner $owner $file}
```

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem | Select *,@{n='Owner';e={(Get-Acl $_).Owner}} | 
             Where {!$_.PSIsContainer -and ($_.Owner -eq 'Domain\name')}
```

On V3 you can simplify this to:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -File | Select *,@{n='Owner';e={(Get-Acl $_).Owner}} | 
             Where {$_.Owner -eq 'Domain\name'}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest I've found is:

```
Get-ChildItem | Get-Acl | Where-Object { $_.Owner -match 'Domain\username' }
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be faster:

```
$Owner = 'user1'
$SID = (Get-ADUser $Owner).sid

Get-ChildItem | 
where { (Get-Acl $_).sddl -like "O:$SID*" } |
select *,@{l='Owner';e={$Owner}}
```

The ACL is stored as an SDDL string. The SID of file owner will always be at the beginning of the SDDL string, prefixed with O:.  NTFS has to resolve the SIDs to an owner name. It takes less time to do a string match for the SID than to do the lookup and then match the name. It's not much, and it won't make much difference just doing a file or 10, but it starts to add up when you start doing thousands of them.

Answer (score 0):

Another variant, but using .NET's `File.GetAccessControl` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.getaccesscontrol?view=netframework-4.8 instead of `Get-Acl` cmdlet.

Credit to [Get File Owner/Author](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42193597/get-file-owner-author)

```
Get-ChildItem <path> -File | Select-Object fullname, LastAccessTime, LastWriteTime, CreationTime, @{N='Owner';E={$_.GetAccessControl().Owner}}
```