# Get File Owner/Author

Tags: powershell

I have the below script retrieving specific file types from the C: drive and outputting specific file properties to a delimited CSV file. I would like to be able to also retrieve the file owner and authors. Any help is very much appreciated.

```
# PowerShell script to list the .xlsx  files under the C Drive
$Dir = get-childitem "C:" -recurse -force
$List = $Dir | where {$_.extension -eq ".xlsx"}
$List |Select-Object fullname, LastAccessTime, LastWriteTime, CreationTime |Export-Csv -path C:\Scripts\xlsx.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Small aside: you can use the `-filter` option of Get-ChildItem rather than applying `where` to the output.

Answer (score 23):

As soon as I posted this I was able to find a solution. I added `@{N='Owner';E={$_.GetAccessControl().Owner}}` to the select-object string. It now looks like this:

```
$List | Select-Object fullname, LastAccessTime, LastWriteTime, CreationTime, @{N='Owner';E={$_.GetAccessControl().Owner}} | Export-Csv -path C:\Scripts\xlsx.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 8):

Chris Adkins answer works in PowerShell 5.1 but didn't work for me using PowerShell 7.1.

> `@{N='Owner';E={$_.GetAccessControl().Owner}}`

I found that this works in both versions 5.1 and 7.1:

```
$List | Select Fullname, LastAccessTime, LastWriteTime, CreationTime, @{N="Owner";E={ (Get-Acl $_.FullName).Owner }}
```

Comment: I tried this in my lab environment and it looks like GetAccessControl() is about 4 times faster than Get-Acl. If GetAccessControl() is no longer available in Powershell 7 and beyond, that's going to be a huge performance problem at least in our organization.

Comment: They just moved the method since dotnet core, so pwsh 7 as well.

Using the following expression instread: `[IO.FileSystemAclExtensions]::GetAccessControl((Get-Item .)).Owner`

Comment: How to get list of the file Author rather than the Owner?  I understands this is different