# How to get the company property from Microsoft Office files with file extension doc, docx, pptx, xlsx?

Tags: powershell, properties

I'm trying to get `Owner` and `Company` properties from Microsoft Office files (Excel, PowerPoint, Word) using PowerShell.
Now I'm able to get the `Owner` using the code below got from: [Get File Owner/Author](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42193597/get-file-owner-author)

```
  Get-ChildItem | Select-Object -Property  Fullname, @{Name = 'Owner';Expression = {$PSItem.GetAccessControl().Owner}}
```

But I haven't found a way to show the `Company` property that appears in `Details` section of a file when we do **right click** --> **Properties** --> **Details** in *Windows File Explorer*.

Is there a way to get the `Company` property by command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a shell com object you can do this by passing the string of the property you want to access to the items [ExtendedProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shellfolderitem-extendedproperty)  method. You can do this for example with a single file like this:

```
$sourceFolder = "C:\Users\path"
$fileName = "test.docx"
$items = (New-Object -com shell.application).NameSpace($sourceFolder).items()
Write-Output $items.item($fileName).ExtendedProperty("Company")
```

First get all folder items then select the file you want and the property you want, in this case "Company". Combining with what you have we can do something like this:

```
$sourceFolder = "C:\Users\mypath\folder"
$items = (New-Object -com shell.application).NameSpace($sourceFolder).items()


Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceFolder | Select-Object -Property  Fullname, @{Name = 'Owner';Expression = {$PSItem.GetAccessControl().Owner}}, 
 @{Name = 'Company';Expression = {$items.Item($_.Name).ExtendedProperty("Company")}}
```

###### OUTPUT

```
FullName                              Owner Company     
--------                              ----- -------     
C:\Users\mypath\folder\test - Copy.docx       zzz  COMPANY
C:\Users\mypath\folder\test.docx              ABC COMPANY
```

##### Update

As requested, I have made updates to work if `-recurse` is used. The issue is that we will have to get the new [FolderItems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/folderitems-item) by running

```
$items = (New-Object -com shell.application).NameSpace($sourceFolder).items()
```

for each sub folder.
So instead of having it all combined like above we are going to have to separate it out. We first get all items using `Get-ChildItem -Recurse` and save it to a variable. Then we loop through those items. We query the company information like before but only if it's a file (not directory). We also check if the current file in the list is in a different directory than the `FolderItems` we have. If it is different then we query the new folder. We save everything to a `PSCustomObject`.

```
$sourceFolder = "C:\Users\path\folder"
# Get FolderItems
$items = (New-Object -com shell.application).NameSpace($sourceFolder).items()
$currentFolder = $sourceFolder

$list = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceFolder -Recurse

$fileInfo = foreach ($item in $list){
   # get current item's folder
   $itemParentFolder = ($item.PsParentPath -Split "::")[1]
   # only check if item is not a directory 
   if ($item.GetType().Name -ne 'DirectoryInfo'){
        # if the current items parent folder is different from current folder get the new folder items 
        if ($itemParentFolder -ne $currentFolder){
                $currentFolder = $itemParentFolder
                $items = (New-Object -com shell.application).NameSpace($currentFolder).items()
        }
            # get company
            $company = $items.Item($item.Name).ExtendedProperty("Company")
    }
    # directory so there is no company info
    else{
        $company = ""
    }
    # get owner
    $owner = (Get-Acl $item.FullName).Owner

    # set custom object values
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        FullName = $item.FullName
        Owner = $owner
        Company = $company
    }
   
}

Write-Output $fileInfo
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. It seems to work. I only was trying to list all files in folder and subfolders recursive, I´ve added `-recurse` like this Get-ChildItem -recurse -Path $sourceFolder...` but in this case the output only shows the owner. Do you know how to print recursive owner and company for all files in folder and subfolders?

Comment: @RasecMalkic I think we would have to create a for loop and change the `NameSpace` for each folder. Since when getting the items in a folder using this method there is no way to specify to do recursively as far as I have seen.  `$items = (New-Object -com shell.application).NameSpace($sourceFolder).items()` . I'll try to think of a workaround.

Comment: @RasecMalkic I have updated it for using with `-recurse`

Comment: Excellent!!! Not sure how this magic works, but it works. Thanks so much for your help